# how to fix the border of bottom don't tuch the whole div?

Tags: css

HTML

```
<div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
width: 500px ;
height: 300px ;
background-color: red ;
border-bottom: dotted;
```

output of this , border touch with total div width i want just 50% of div's width is border and center in div .

Comment: Use a pseudo-element, set its width as half, position it and give it the border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.div {
  width: 500px ;
  height: 300px ;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.div:before {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
  margin-left: -125px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
</div>
```